# Should we split [windows-azure-queues] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

The [windows-azure-queues](/questions/tagged/windows-azure-queues) tag (only 74 questions) can confusingly be used to refer to two quite different technologies where the only thing the have in common is that they both run on Azure, Azure Storage Queues and Azure Service Bus queues.  The current tag I'm sure exists because in the early days of Azure there was only one type of queue so would have sufficed.

Quite often when a question is asked about "Azure Queues" the first comment against it is to clarify exactly which technology is being used.  If the question doesn't specify the technology then I know that's no guarantee they'll get the right tags either, but at least we could tag the question appropriately for the future.

I'd suggest that in keeping with other Azure tags [azure-storage-queues](/questions/tagged/azure-storage-queues) and [azure-servicebus-queues](/questions/tagged/azure-servicebus-queues) could be good alternatives (the last one seems quite verbose though)